# Как блоки меню поместить друг под друга?

Tags: html, css

Чтобы при одном активном блоке остальные могли отъехать в низ.

```css
body {
  font-family: 'Lucida Grande', 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  margin: 0;
  font-size: 13px;
  text-align: center;
  background: black
}

ul {
  text-align: left;
  display: inline;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 15px 4px 17px 0;
  list-style: none;

}
ul li {
  font: bold 12px/18px sans-serif;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  padding: 15px 20px;
  background: #00BCD4;
  cursor: pointer;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.2s;
  -moz-transition: all 0.2s;
  -ms-transition: all 0.2s;
  -o-transition: all 0.2s;
  transition: all 0.2s;
  color: #fff;
}
ul li:hover {

  font-size: 22px;
}
ul li ul {
  padding: 0.5;
  position: absolute;
  top: 48px;
  left: 0;
  width: 150px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: none;
  -moz-box-shadow: none;
  box-shadow: none;
  display: none;
  opacity: 0.5;
  visibility: hidden;
  -webkit-transiton: opacity 0.5s;
  -moz-transition: opacity 0.5s;
  -ms-transition: opacity 0.5s;
  -o-transition: opacity 0.5s;
  -transition: opacity 0.5s;

}
ul li ul li { 
  display: block;
}
ul li ul li:hover { }
ul li:hover ul {
  display: block;
  opacity: 0.5;
  visibility: visible;
}
.home {
  border-top-left-radius: 3px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 3px;
}
.contact {
  border-top-right-radius: 3px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 3px;
}
menu {
  padding-top: 200px;
  opacity: 0.5;
}
```

```html
<menu>
<ul>
  <li>
    raz
    <ul>
      <li>dva</li>
      <li>three</li>
      <li>four</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  </ul>
  <ul>
  <li>
    dva
    <ul>
      <li>dva</li>
      <li>three</li>
      <li>four</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  </ul>
  <ul>
  <li>
    three
    <ul>
      <li>dva</li>
      <li>three</li>
      <li>four</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  </ul>
          </ul>  
  </nav>  
</div>
</menu>
```

Comment: И как можно сделать, чтобы был фиксированный блок во внутренних вкладках и при наведении на одну из низ рядом появлялся текст?

Comment: По вашему описанию сложно представить, что именно вам нужно. Добавьте изображение желаемого.